# pushing back a data using std::list

Tags: c++, list, std

I have a defined type and created a list of this type.

```
Message theMessage;
std::list<Message> LM;
```

Now this statement

```
LM.push_back(theMessage);
```

gives me this error:

```
/../gcc-4.1.2/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.0/../../../../include/c++/4.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h:104: error: no matching function for call to ‘
SharedTypes::Message::Message(const SharedTypes::Message&)’
```

The constructor looks like

```
explicit Message(Message & aMsg)
{}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What Luchian said. Also, is there are reason your copy constructor takes a non-const reference? I don't think that's hurting you here, but it could in other situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested constructor should be:

1. `explicit Message(const Message & aMsg)`
2. declared as `public`

If you can't change this then consider using container of smart pointer, like `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Message>>`, or `boost::ptr_list<Message>`

Answer (score 2):

My bad:

```
explicit Message(const Message & aMsg)
{}
```

`explicit` does work, but you have to pass the parameter by `const` reference.

Comment: He also, most likely, will need to make it a const reference as well, so that it can be used when the input is constant.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I have not wrote the constructor. So please give a solution for my code.

Comment: `Message theMessage;` and `std::list<Message> LM;
` and `LM.push_back(theMessage);
`

Comment: @mahmood: If you can't fix the copy constructor, you probably have to do something different.  You might be able to do this with a list of smart pointers to your object, for example.

Comment: @mahmood how about adding `//` before your lines? That'd work... I mean... if you can't fix something that's obviously broken...